# Java : set a constant as a compilation argument

Tags: java, ant, compilation, constants, manifest

I'd like to set a constant into my java program, but I don't want it to be in the code, but rather as a compilation parameter. How can I do this ? As a manifest attribute ? How can I recover the value ?

The point of this is to run an automated multiple compilation changing this constant.

I'm from C world, so perhaps it's a bad idea in Java. I'm open to all suggestion.

The application : I have a salt included in a hash, and I want to change the salt easily.

Comment: java don't have macro like c.. are you finding something like macro?

Comment: It is not natural for Java to push a constant into the bytecode which is coming from the outside.

Comment: You could use command line parameters at execution time, but I have no clue whether it is possible to have parameters set at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use system properties specified on the command line:

```
java -Dmyprop=myvalue yourapp
```

and then access it in your code as:

```
System.getProperty("myprop")
```

Like other comments have said, unless you want to get into bytecode manipulation there is no way to inject a true code constant. If you want to go the bytecode manipulation route you could look into AST transforms (java or groovy) or a project like Javasist, but those would be quite a bit more complex solutions.

Comment: Shouldn't look so far, it's just like C defines :D I have no need of a "real" constant, so this solution will be ok. However I take note of everybody's advice about the non-usal usage of this solution. I promise I won't do it often.

Comment: This is a runtime solution, right? This has to be set every time they program is run? Is there any way to do this when compiling to only set it once?

Answer (score 1):

This sort of configuration is usually stored in a configuration file (usually XML or properties) and then read at run-time. You can generate the configuration file at build time automatically with a customized build script or you can just put the file in manually.

The other alternative is to use command line parameters or environment variables to pass the configuration in. The file approach is likely to be simplest and most robust though.

Comment: Tanks for your answer. My problem is that I don't want the user to know the salt, that would be the case by using configuration files. I don't take this as an absolute security, but it's better this way for my application case. Also I want all user of a same version have the same salt, so machine dependent configuration is excluded too.

Comment: A salt is useless unless you change it per user anyway. Keeping a salt secret doesn't matter. The point is to stop people using easy mass processing to crack passwords since salting changes each individual password.